# buildozer docker container cant compile sdl2 (cpufeatures)

Tags: python, docker, android-ndk, kivy

So, its quite a long story but I'm trying to get OpenCV to work with android. After some research I discovered this Dockerfile (https://github.com/tom333/mycamerai/blob/master/Dockerfile) which presumable provides a workaround to an issue with the actual official Dockerfile. after running it with the following command `docker run -it -v "C:\Users\grass\OneDrive\Desktop\Openceevee":/buildozer -w /buildozer fe5e50d6a65f  android debug deploy run`

it started erroring out because of SDK versions. Suspecting I have a wrong .spec file si modified .spec file from the same Github repo as this docker file I used. now however it errors out building sdl2, particularly on CPU features.

```
 python3 said it is already built, skipping
[INFO]:    Building sdl2 for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    -> directory context /buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/jni
[INFO]:    -> running ndk-build V=1 NDK_DEBUG=1
           working: make: *** No rule to make target `/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/sources/android/cpufeatures/cpu-features.c', needed by `/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/...(and 96 more)  Exception in thread background thread for pid 434:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 1633, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2557, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2261, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 861, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_2:

  RAN: /opt/android-ndk/ndk-build V=1 NDK_DEBUG=1
```

Following bit from stdout looked interesting to me:

```
  STDOUT:
Android NDK: WARNING:/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/jni/application/src/Android.mk:main: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lpython3.8m
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
Android NDK:     current module
/opt/android-ndk/build/core/build-binary.mk:672: Android NDK: Module main depends on undefined modules: python_shared
rm -f /buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/libs/armeabi-v7a/*
rm -f /buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
rm -f /buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2/libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
```

as it contained warnings about the python version. However, running the official docker buildozer image does not cause the same issue and works fine. I'm putting NDK tag in this question but just as it seems relevant. In reality ik nothing about NDK.